# how to take an array of 8 digit strings as input in angular and pass to node.js backend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mean-stack

I am trying to take an array of 8 digit strings as input from angular and pass it as a parameter to node.js endpoint as follows,the following works great if I just have one string ,as you can see below hard coding string of arrays to `req.query.params`works great in the node.js api but how do I take an array of 8 digit strings as input and pass to node.js?

In html:

```
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)]="enteredValue"></textarea>
<hr>
<button (click)="get_radar_lifecycle_data()">Search</button>
```

in component.ts

```
get_radar_lifecycle_data(){
     const params = new HttpParams().set('params', this.enteredValue);
     this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/radar_life_cycle3',{params})
     .subscribe(response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.newPost = response
      });
}
```

node.js

hard coding string of arrays to `req.query.params`works great

```
app.get("/api/radar_life_cycle3", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
   Radar_life_cycle.find({orgRadar: {$in:["51509646","51643617"]}})
   .then(documents => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
        posts: documents
      });
    });
  });
```

Actual api call

```
app.get("/api/radar_life_cycle3", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.query.params)
   Radar_life_cycle.find({orgRadar: {$in:req.query.params}})
   .then(documents => {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Posts fetched successfully!",
        posts: documents
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Try to use `put` call insted of `get`.

Comment: why put instead of get?how will that fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `.find({orgRadar: {$in:req.query.params.split(',')}})` as it comes from FE in such comma separated values format, and to convert it to array of strings split(',') should work fine

Comment: how to ensure that the user enters in such comma seperated format?